# PDF file is not taking all the CSS

Tags: html, css, pdf, width

I am using dl dt dd tags in my HTML page. I have some table structure. And in a row I have four columns. I have given same 'width' to each column (for dd element) in HTML.
Also I have functionality to download this HTML page in PDF also.

But the problem is when we are downloading the page into PDF. The PDF file in not taking the 'width' for columns (dd element).

I have given the width in HTML page in Pixels.

Is there any way we can fix it by CSS to set width that can we applicable for HTML and PDF both the files?

Comment: Could you create a simple example and test it shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example